# Add comment to storyboard localization

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to add comment to a localized string **in storyboard**?

```
/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Some text"; comment = "This is the comment to help translator" ObjectID = "0N3-up-Ts6"; */
"0N3-up-Ts6.text" = "Some text";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears you can:

[image]

This produces:

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Title"; ObjectID = "KjJ-0v-J2z"; Note = "Comment for Localizer"; */
"KjJ-0v-J2z.text" = "Title";
```

Comment: This is crashing Xcode 9 swift 4.... any workaround or reason on why this may be happening? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546563/xcode-9-crash-on-label-localizer-comment-edition

Comment: This works properly on Xcode 9.4.1. Very useful to mark text that doesnt need translation with a tag for later processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a user-defined attribute:

[image: User-defined attribute in Xcode]

It will appear thus in the XIB:

```
<view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="s1b-V9-EN7">
  <rect key="frame" x="20" y="45" width="728" height="959"/>
  <subviews>
     <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" v
       <rect key="frame" x="215" y="688" width="92" height="21"/>
       // . . . . etc . . . . 
       <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
          <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="string" keyPath="localization_comment" value="&quot;Some text to help the translator">
       </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
     </label>
  </subviews>
</view>
```

Comment: Will it appear in the .strings file?

Comment: No, this is not the strings file. This is the storyboard, as you requested. Perhaps you meant to ask how to automate making a label refer to a strings file, and to add comments to a .strings file? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: the question is very clear, including the example. Have you had a look at it? `comment = "This is the comment to help translator"`

Comment: I think there was some miscommunication, I don't know what I said which made you upset. Anyway, I modified the question to be more clear about the `.strings` file.

Comment: Just saw this, thought it may be of interest for your situation:
https://github.com/angelolloqui/AGi18n

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer; @jjrscott's should be. Apple made the function of the Notes text field clearer in more recent versions of Xcode by adding the "Comment for Localizer" placeholder text.

Comment: Indeed @NRitH it does seem like things changed four years later. Apple gets there! :joy: JastinBall, can you update it?